# VS2015 - Change HTML Element Selected Colour

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, less

I don't know how, but I have changed the highlighted background(?) colour of a HTML element to be the below colour and want to change it back. I've looked through the options but cannot find the one that changes the colour of this.

I've tried resetting my User Data and that didn't change it at all.

[image: HTML Element Selection Colour]
I've also noticed that this has changed the colour of brackets in LESS/CSS files so I don't know if this is any help to anyone able to answer this question?

[image: LESS/CSS Bracket Highlighted Colour]

Comment: I think, Tools >. Option > Environment > Font and color

Comment: @sani I've looked in there, but I can't find the right item to edit to change the colour back to default.

Comment: Try Highlighted Reference >> Item Background

Answer (score 0):

[image: See the image, you can change it back to normal there]

You can get to here by selecting :

Tools >. Option > Environment > Font and color

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've updated the background colour for Highlighted Reference but this doesn't seem to have updated the background colour when I click the li tag name https://s32.postimg.org/5i0lgep51/highlighted_references.png

Comment: The Highlighted Reference did the trick for me. May be try and reset the values to default or change the skin to light ?

Comment: I'm clicking on the li text in the li tag. I changed the skin to light/blue and the highlighted reference works as intended. I really don't like the light or blue skins though so I guess I'll have to deal with this unreadable selection bg/fg for now...

Comment: Did you try setting other color other than black ? As it is a dark theme black might not work. But its weird kinda though !

Comment: Yeah I tried a multitude of colours. I even got a colleague to send me his exported settings and it didn't change anything! Going to redownload Visual Studio and install a completely blank version to see if there's any difference.